# set_include_path sets path but path doesn't work

Tags: php

I've read nearly all of the posts about set_include_path but I haven't found a post that I really understand yet.

I'm trying to use UserSpice for my logins on a new site.  I already have a file structure for the site of course, and I thought I would be able to simply add the UserSpice folder to that structure and then use set_include_path to access all of the files within UserSpice. But I guess I just don't understand the function or paths in general.

This is my code:
    `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mynewsite\userSpice');`

This is the result:
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'users/init.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\mynewsite\userSpice') in E:\xampp\htdocs\mynewsite\index.php on line 10

The 'users' folder is a subfolder of 'mynewsite/userSpice' so I thought that the path would allow access to that folder.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe there's a permission problem.

Comment: UserSpice bases all if its paths relative to where that z_us_root file is sitting. It's kind of a beacon in the file system and everything goes from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to access to the required path:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/mynewsite/userSpice/users/init.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/mynewsite/userSpice/users/includes/header.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/mynewsite/userSpice/users/includes/navigation.php';
```